# REGEXP_REPLACE in Oracle replacing character 'n' and 'r' instead of replacing new line or space

Tags: oracle, newline, regexp-replace

```
SELECT 

COALESCE(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(Col_1, '(<.*?>)|(/(\r\n)+|\r+|\n+|Chr(9)+/i)|(/^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s))', ' ',1,0, 'm')), TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(Col2, '(<.*?>)|(/(\r\n)+|\r+|\n+|Chr(9)+/i)|(/^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s))', ' ', 1, 0, 'm'))) AS SNDR_TO_RCVR_INF1

FROM TABLE_NAME.
```

This replaces the characters 'r' or 'n' from Col_1 or Col 2 instead of new line.

I guess it is because I used \r and \n in the syntax.

But then what should I do so the syntax recognizes /n instead of n (newline) or /r instead of r?

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate in the character sequences for carriage return and new line (and tab) instead:

```
'(<.*?>)|(/(' ||chr(13)||chr(10)|| ')+|' ||chr(13)|| '+|' ||chr(10)|| '+|' ||chr(9)|| '+/i)|(/^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s))'
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=eb0d756c7a5b4c6fc548d5dfb0309171)

You can probably simplify that further, but that's a separate issue...

Comment: thanks for the solution. now the code is not replacing 'n' or 'r'. But the column now has xml tags/CdtrRefInf, CdtrRef etc in the values. Is there any way to get rid of the tags?

Comment: @Raj - it won't add any tags, so those must be in your original data - you didn't provide any sample data to work from, or the expected output for that data.... Although, somehow I'd lost a `*` when copying that into db<>fiddle. I've added that back in so that's now removing tags. (Using regex to manipulate XML isn't generally a good idea though.)